# Convert mp3 to flac files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, audio, google-speech-api

I'm trying to find a way of easily converting mp3 to flac files using ruby (preferably) server-side. 
I have a horde of audio that I would like to transcribe using the google speech api but it only accepts flac. (among other things). 
Can find a flac2mp3 convertor that will work on a laptop, went through the code and unfortunately seems to be just calling a system command which requires having the codecs installed locally. .

Is there an api maybe that will do this for me? 
Or an easy way to install the codecs and run this sort of command on heroku.

Comment: Recommending third party resources is off topic for Stack Overflow -- you'll have to find another way to phrase your request or this question is likely to be closed. Also, does it really make sense to convert from a lossy format to a lossless format?

Comment: FWIW: http://superuser.com/questions/457548/how-can-i-convert-an-mp3-to-flac/457549

Answer (score 2):

@orde linked to an exiting question which recommends the following:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 output.flac
```

This is not a ruby command, it is a system command (i.e. unix or windows)

To call a system command from ruby, you can use backticks or `system`.

For example, after you've installed `ffmpeg` to your system

```
def convert_mp3_to_flac(mp3_path)
  flac_path = mp3_path.gsub(".mp3", ".flac")
  system("ffmpeg -i #{mp3_path} #{flac_path}")
end
```

Comment: Yeah, I got that far after reading through the code in the gem. 
Just seems like an utter ballache. Will need to somehow integrate an ffmpeg buildpack into heroku to be able to do it.
Don't know why google can't just allow formats that people actually use...

Comment: this one seems to work: https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/jonathanong/heroku-buildpack-ffmpeg-latest ... after you add it you need to commit some arbitrary code change and `git push heroku master` to trigger a new build, then `heroku run "ffmpeg --version"` should work